# Unpacking a List of Pandas DataFrames into Separate Tabular DataFrames

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to turn a pandas list of df tuples into the len number of separate DataFrames through a function. I found a simple sample DataFrame that is comprised of different animal types. Instead of creating a list of DataFrames in tuple format, I wanted to have them pushed out into separate DataFrames tables (not tuples, etc) without calling the position of the df one-by-one (i.e. `animals[0]`) since I do not know how long any given list will be. Any recommendations?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'animal': 'cat dog cat fish dog cat cat'.split(),
'size': list('SSMMMLL'),
'weight': [8, 10, 11, 1, 20, 12, 12],
'adult': [False] * 5 + [True] * 2})
```

I inspect the df:

```
df

    animal  size    weight  adult
0   cat S   8   False
1   dog S   10  False
2   cat M   11  False
3   fish    M   1   False
4   dog M   20  False
5   cat L   12  True
6   cat L   12  True
```

I then split the df into three smaller dfs through grouping by `'animal'`:

```
animals = list(df.groupby('animal'))

for a in animals:
  print(a, end='\n\n')

('cat',   animal size  weight  adult
0    cat    S       8  False
2    cat    M      11  False
5    cat    L      12   True
6    cat    L      12   True)

('dog',   animal size  weight  adult
1    dog    S      10  False
4    dog    M      20  False)

('fish',   animal size  weight  adult
3   fish    M       1  False)
```

Next, I verify if animals is indeed a list:

```
type(animals)
list
```

I then try to extract the first item among the animals list, only to find out that the first item of the list is a tuple and not a DataFrame:

```
animals[0]

('cat',   animal size  weight  adult
 0    cat    S       8  False
 2    cat    M      11  False
 5    cat    L      12   True
 6    cat    L      12   True)
```

```
type(animals[0])
tuple
```

Is there any way to push out separate DataFrame tables for cat, dog, and fish without calling them one-by-one? In my real life application, I cannot anticipate the number of tables I would generate from the list of DataFrame tuples.

Comment: @yatu's solution is an elegant way of achieving this but Just in case you are looking for `df[['cat' in x for x in df['animal']]]`  or `df[df['animal'].str.contains('cat', regex=True)]`

Answer (score 3):

Each element is a `key/value` `tuple`, each key being the grouping key as a result of the `GroupBy`. Instead build a `tuple` from the `groupby` object, and use it to build a dictionary:

```
animals = dict(tuple(df.groupby('animal')))
```

And then just access the elements by the grouping keys:

```
print(animals['cat'])
animal size  weight  adult
0    cat    S       8  False
2    cat    M      11  False
5    cat    L      12   True
6    cat    L      12   True
```

Comment: Very Efficient and minimal way of doing it. Great answer @yatu

Comment: This is an elegant way of doing +1

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
animals = {}
for name, group in df.groupby('animal'):
    animals[name] = group
print(animals['cat'])
```

OR

```
animals = {name: group for name, group in df.groupby('animal')}
```

OR if you wanna access a particular group (I think this is the best)

```
df.groupby('animal').get_group('cat')

  animal size  weight  adult
0    cat    S       8  False
2    cat    M      11  False
5    cat    L      12   True
6    cat    L      12   True
```

Name will be the name of group i.e dog, cat, etc and group will be the dataframe.

Comment: Appreciate the change, it helps in understanding for posterity +1

Comment: What about adding `df[['cat' in x for x in df['animal']]]` in place of `cat` you may choose `dog` etc..

Comment: @pygo The OP says "I cannot anticipate the number of tables"